# Direction interpolation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, game-development

[image]

I have tree vector A, B, and D. Is there a way to determinate how close vector D is to A, B and C and represent it in value from 0 to 1? Also compare results (A to D, B to D, and C to D) should sum to 1.

All vectors are normalized end represent direction.

Comment: wouldn't [`Vector3.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) pretty much do this? `For normalized vectors Dot returns 1 if they point in exactly the same direction, -1 if they point in completely opposite directions and zero if the vectors are perpendicular.`

Comment: Dot product won't do the trick. 

I try to calculate an inverse lerp for three vectors A, B and C using D vector..

Comment: so you mean something like [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1271974/inverselerp-for-vector3.html?childToView=1274648#answer-1274648)? Still a bit unclear: I see that `1` would mean it is e.g. fully equal to `A` ... but how do you imagine any other value? What would `0` mean? I see how you can interpolate (and inverse) between two vectors ... but I don't quite understand how you want to deal with 3 vectors here ...

Comment: This could be one of those cases where describing the practical application and problem might lead easier to community help than the numeric approach.

Comment: I try to get an arary of values between 0 - 1.  For example, if i revive [0, 1, 0] that will mean that vector D is "equal" to vector B. If i receive something like [0.3, 0.5, 0.2], D will be smoothing between A, B and C. Mostly like B, least like C.

Comment: That sounds like dot will still work. Just shift it from the -1->1 range to the 0->1 range. That means plus 1 and divided by two.

Comment: What is the actual goal here? If the idea is to represent some kind of rotation you should be using quaternions for interpolation rather than vectors.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Dot when calculating it for D and A, D and B, and D and C (for a case I presented in my drawing). will return values x >= 0.7.

Comment: In another words I try to calculate how meny A, B and C i mast use to get D.

Comment: @Łukasz again I see this is pretty straight forward using two input vectors `A`, `B` and the "output" vector `D` ... but how is this supposed to be working exactly for the third vector? Lets say you have `[1, 0, 0]` -> equals A. Now as it rotates slightly you want to reduce the `A` value .. **but** which of he other values shall be increased in exchange?

Comment: As I see it you can either map it to a certain percentage of equality (see Dot) and simply make sure they sum up to 1 using a factor **but** => The highest value means most similar to that vector, not necessarily that there is actually that amount of similarity (I hope it gets somewhat clear what I'm trying to say ^^) ... or you can get an exact match (see Dot) **but** => they won't sum up to 1

Comment: It would really help if you were to explain the goal of this question because it sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think there are two options

- You forget about them summing up to `1` and rather simply ask "How much does each individual vector match the given result vector `D`?"

  For this something like the following should do it.

  - Get the [`Vector3.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) for each vector against `D`
  - Map these dot products from the range `-1 | 1` into the range `0 | 1`

  Something like

  ```
  public static float[] GetResults(Vector3[] inputVectors /*A,B,C*/, Vetcor3 resultVector /*D*/)
  {
      var results = new float[inputVectors.Length];

      // In a first iteration simply get all Dot products
      for(var i = 0; i < inputVector.Length; i++)
      {
          // 1 -> equal direction
          // -1 -> exactly contrary direction
          // 0 -> perpendicular
          var result = Vector3.Dot(resultVector, inputVectors[i]);
          // map to range 0 to 1
          result = (1f + result) / 2f;
          results[i] = result;
      }

      return results;
  }
  ```

  You might get a result like e.g. `[0.7, 0.5, 0.2]`
- Or you actually want as a result an array of probabilities or in simple words: "Which vector matches with the given vector `D` the most?"

  For this basically do the same as before but additionally

  - Sum them all up and use the result as a factor so that in total you get a value of `100%` (`1`)

  This would mean what you get as results are probabilities not actually degree of equality, you just get the vector which is "closest" to D

  ```
  // Linq provides queries against IEnumerable types
  // I used it for a shorthand to sum up all numbers in an array see below
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  public static float[] GetResults(Vector3[] inputVectors /*A,B,C*/, Vetcor3 resultVector /*D*/)
  {
      ... // Same as above 


      // Additionally now get the sum of them all using Linq -> this is the inverse factor
      var sum = results.Sum();
      // or without Linq basically
      //var sum = 0f;
      //foreach(var result in results)
      //{
      //    sum += result;
      //}

      // in a second iteration now divide all results by the "sum"
      // => after this they will sum up to exactly 1
      for(var i = 0; i < inputVector.Length; i++)
      {
          results[i] = results[i] / sum;
      }

      return results;
  }
  ```

  For the same values as above you might get something like `[0.5, 0.357, 0.143]`

---

What I tried to say before is:

Let's assume you get some really bad matching vectors like e.g. first method would return

```
0.02, 0.1, 0.01
```

the second method would return e.g.

```
0.08, 0.77, 0.15
```

so this would make you assume that `B` is a pretty good match while actually it is only the less bad match between three really bad matches.

Comment: Yess yess join me in answering math questions on stack overflow ;)

Comment: @Łukasz note the update at the bottom where I explained my previous concerns a bit better I hope ;)

Comment: @derHugo Unfortunately, your solution isn't completely, correct.  Simply put. When you match D vector to one of other vectors you won't get result like [0, 1, 0]. Anyway thx for help.